# How to extract pixel values from fluorescence image of 96 well microplate in R

Tags: r, loops, image-processing

I am having trouble extracting pixel intensity values from images of microtiter plates in R. I have used EBImage to threshold and segment an image, but when I do this I lose the actual intensity values from the original image.

Starting with a .png image like this:

[image: 96 well plate]

I need to identify each individual well and calculate the average intensity within each (they are leaf discs in the well plate). Thus I would want to have 81 values from this image.

Next, I need to extract those values in a matrix that I can use to perform operations from separate images of the same plate. So the segmentation needs to be re-usable so I can just read in the other images of this same plate and extract the respective well values. The images are all the exact same size, and the location of wells does not change. There are hundreds of images of this plate taken over several hours.

So far I've segmented and thresholded, but this causes loss of the original image intensities.
Here are the attributes of the original image posted above:

```
print(fo)
Image 
  colorMode    : Color 
  storage.mode : double 
  dim          : 696 520 3 
  frames.total : 3 
  frames.render: 1 

imageData(object)[1:5,1:6,1]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

```
###progress so far

library(tidyverse)
library("EBImage")

#read in image
fo <- readImage("image.png")

#crop excess
fo <-  fo[99:589,79:437,1:3]

#adaptive thresholding 
threshold <- thresh(fo,w=25,h=25,offset=0.01)

#use bwlabel to segment thresholded image
fo_lab <- bwlabel(threshold[,,2])

nmask = watershed(distmap(threshold), 10 )
display(colorLabels(nmask), all=TRUE)
```

Which would leave me with this image:

[image: thresholded and segmented well plate]

The values I would get in fo_lab are based on the thresholded intensity for each region, so they don't effectively capture the true difference in intensity between wells. More importantly, I need to carry those values to use in mathematical operations on the exact same extracted areas from proceeding images.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky. Let's start by reproducing your data by reading the image straight from this Stack Overflow page:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library("EBImage")

fo <- readImage("https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFkmD.png")

#crop excess
fo <-  fo[99:589,79:437,1:3]

#adaptive thresholding 
threshold <- thresh(fo, w = 25, h = 25, offset = 0.01)

#use bwlabel to segment thresholded image
fo_lab <- bwlabel(threshold[,,2])
```

Now, the key to this is realising that `fo_lab` contains an array of pixels which are labelled according to the group (i.e. the well) they are in. There are also a few stray pixels which have been assigned to their own groups, so we remove anything with fewer than a hundred pixels by writing 0s into `fo_lab` at these locations:

```
fo_table <- table(fo_lab)
fo_lab[fo_lab %in% as.numeric(names(fo_table)[fo_table < 100])] <- 0
```

Now we have only the pixels that are on a well labelled with anything other than a zero, and we can ensure we have the correct number of wells:

```
fo_wells <- as.numeric(names(table(fo_lab)))[-1]
length(fo_wells)
#> [1] 81
```

So now we can create a data frame that records the position (the centroid) of each well:

```
df <- as.data.frame(computeFeatures.moment(fo_lab))
```

And we can add the average intensity of the pixels within each well on the original image to that data frame:

```
df$intensity <- sapply(fo_wells, function(x) mean(fo[fo_lab == x]))
```

So we have a data frame with the required results:

```
head(df)
#>       m.cx     m.cy m.majoraxis m.eccentricity    m.theta intensity
#> 1 462.2866 17.76579    29.69468      0.3301601 -0.2989824 0.1229826
#> 2 372.9313 20.51608    29.70871      0.1563481 -1.0673974 0.2202901
#> 3 417.3410 19.64526    29.43567      0.2725219  0.4858422 0.1767944
#> 4 328.2435 21.87536    29.73790      0.1112710 -0.9316834 0.3010003
#> 5 283.9245 22.69954    29.17318      0.2366731 -1.4561670 0.5471162
#> 6 239.0390 24.15465    29.39590      0.1881874  0.6315008 0.3799093
```

So we have each plate recorded according to its x, y position and we have its average intensity. To prove this, let's plot the original image in ggplot and overlay the intensity values on each plate:

```
img_df <- reshape2::melt(as.matrix(as.raster(as.array(fo))))

ggplot(img_df, aes(Var1, Var2, fill = value)) + 
  geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  geom_text(inherit.aes = FALSE, data = df, color = "red",
            aes(x = m.cx, y = m.cy, label = round(intensity, 3))) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

We can see that the whitest plates have the highest intensities and the darker plates have lower intensities.

In terms of making sure successive plates are comparable, note that the output of `computeFeatures.moment(fo_lab)` will always produce the labelling in the same order:

```r
ggplot(img_df, aes(Var1, Var2, fill = value)) + 
  geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  geom_text(inherit.aes = FALSE, data = df, color = "red",
            aes(x = m.cx, y = m.cy, label = seq_along(m.cx))) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

So you can use this to identify wells in subsequent plates.

Putting this all together, you can have a function that takes the image and spits out the intensities of each well, like this:

```r
well_intensities <- function(img) {
  fo <- readImage(img)[99:589,79:437,1:3]
  fo_lab <- bwlabel(thresh(fo, w = 25, h = 25, offset = 0.01)[,,2])
  fo_table <- table(fo_lab)
  fo_lab[fo_lab %in% as.numeric(names(fo_table)[fo_table < 100])] <- 0
  fo_wells <- as.numeric(names(table(fo_lab)))[-1]
  data.frame(well = seq_along(fo_wells),
             intensity = sapply(fo_wells, function(x) mean(fo[fo_lab == x])))
}
```

Which allows you to do:

```r
well_intensities("https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFkmD.png")
#>    well intensity
#> 1     1 0.1229826
#> 2     2 0.2202901
#> 3     3 0.1767944
#> 4     4 0.3010003
#> 5     5 0.5471162
#> 6     6 0.3799093
#> 7     7 0.2266809
#> 8     8 0.2691313
#> 9     9 0.1973300
#> 10   10 0.1219945
#> 11   11 0.1041047
#> 12   12 0.1858798
#> 13   13 0.1853668
#> 14   14 0.3065456
#> 15   15 0.4998599
#> 16   16 0.4173711
#> 17   17 0.3521405
#> 18   18 0.4614704
#> 19   19 0.2955793
#> 20   20 0.2511733
#> 21   21 0.1841083
#> 22   22 0.2669468
#> 23   23 0.3062121
#> 24   24 0.5471972
#> 25   25 0.7279144
#> 26   26 0.4425966
#> 27   27 0.4174344
#> 28   28 0.5155241
#> 29   29 0.5298436
#> 30   30 0.2440677
#> 31   31 0.2971507
#> 32   32 0.1490848
#> 33   33 0.2785301
#> 34   34 0.4392502
#> 35   35 0.4466012
#> 36   36 0.4020305
#> 37   37 0.4516624
#> 38   38 0.3949014
#> 39   39 0.4749804
#> 40   40 0.3820500
#> 41   41 0.2409199
#> 42   42 0.1769995
#> 43   43 0.4764645
#> 44   44 0.3035113
#> 45   45 0.3331184
#> 46   46 0.4859249
#> 47   47 0.8278420
#> 48   48 0.5102533
#> 49   49 0.5754179
#> 50   50 0.4044553
#> 51   51 0.2949486
#> 52   52 0.2020463
#> 53   53 0.3663714
#> 54   54 0.5853405
#> 55   55 0.4011272
#> 56   56 0.8564808
#> 57   57 0.5154415
#> 58   58 0.5178042
#> 59   59 0.5585773
#> 60   60 0.5070020
#> 61   61 0.2637470
#> 62   62 0.2379200
#> 63   63 0.2463080
#> 64   64 0.3840690
#> 65   65 0.3139230
#> 66   66 0.5157990
#> 67   67 0.3606038
#> 68   68 0.3066231
#> 69   69 0.4538155
#> 70   70 0.2935641
#> 71   71 0.1639805
#> 72   72 0.1892272
#> 73   73 0.2618652
#> 74   74 0.3513564
#> 75   75 0.4484937
#> 76   76 0.5032775
#> 77   77 0.3014721
#> 78   78 0.3475152
#> 79   79 0.2001712
#> 80   80 0.2873561
#> 81   81 0.1462936
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you. I might have more questions moving forward, but will post progress in building the analysis pipeline in case it is helpful for others.